# Where does window.location.reload() get its value from?

Tags: javascript, html

Trying reload the current page without the fragment identifier (i.e. hash symbol #) and using the following bit of code to do so which functions correctly:

```
var path = window.location.href.replace(/(\#.*)/,'');
window.location = path;
```

I'm also aware that the above second line could read `window.location.href = path;` which brings me to the next part.

Before arriving at the above code we tried:

```
var path = window.location.href.replace(/(\#.*)/,'');
window.location.href = path;
window.location.reload();
```

However that didn't work for us as the `href` value wasn't seeming to be set and I feel that `reload()` was calling before or instead of the `href = path` bit.

This got me curious, where does the `reload()` function for `window.location` get its value from to reload the page?

If I click around a page jumping between fragment identifiers (perhaps a table of contents) then the address bar updates accordingly and when called, `window.location.reload()` will do so with the correct fragment. Yet if I manually type something in the address bar and then call the `reload()` function it will not load with my manual entry but rather the last 'computer defined' value.

My guess is the user agent (in this particular case Chrome 44) is listening and updating the value which each interaction with the DOM or within the window. I checked out the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#dom-location-reload) and the [MDN Location.reload()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) docs for information and either it wasn't there or I'm too dense to find/understand it.

Can anyone explain to me where `reload()` gets it's value and how it is updated through a users interaction with a page?

What is the exact difference between using `window.location = path` and `window.location.href = path` in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The location (value) only changes after a **successful** navigation! In other words, the `location` instance represents the currently loaded page (including the fragment).

Assigning a new value to `window.location.href` (re)loads a page.

So when you call `window.location.href = path;` the browser wants to load the new URL (the one without the #). But if you immediately call `window.location.reload();` it's like saying "No, wait! Reload the current page (the one with the #)".

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove the "#" part of the url you have to explicitly set:

```
window.location.hash = ""
```

and then call window.location.reload().

`window.location = path` is nothing more than syntactic sugar for `window.location.href = path`.

Comment: This is the valid answer

Comment: I didn't know that `window.location.hash` was possible so +1 for that, however using the code as you say still retains a trailing '#'. My question isn't regarding removing the hash, but rather the `reload()` function. Agreed that the `reload()` function now works as expected but it still don't think this answers my question of what `reload()` is using. Why doesn't `window.location.href = path' work in the same way and set a value?
Might need someone to ELI5 here perhaps. @MarcosPérezGude seems to agree with you @pinturic so maybe either of you can provide more detail.

Comment: the window.location.reload function reload the current document (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp) so it is using the url used to fill the document in the browser. When you change the location by only changing the hash the page is not reloaded but simply the browser is trying to understand the"hash" part of the url for example to find a anchor tags